# How to module exports inside an exported function

Tags: javascript, node.js

how do I achieve such thing?

```js
module.exports = {
    run : async function (param1) {
        if (param1 === 1) // Export success: true
        else // Export success: false
    }
};
```

Basically inside the `run` function I want to be able to export success to be either true or false depending on how the run goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of exporting value. you should return it from the function.and use that values.

```
//run.js

module.exports = {
    run: async function (param1) {
        return param1==1 ? true : false
    }
};


//index.js
let {run}=require("run.js")
run(1).then((shouldRun)=>{
    console.log(shouldRun)//true
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll only be able to return, not export, exports can only be used in ES modules and can only be added as the last line.

Instead, you’d want to return. When you return the Boolean value, you can read it from the call site. See similar example [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/javascript+function+that+return+boolean)